# Silexでのバリデーションメッセージの日本語化

Tags: php, symfony2, silex

Silex 2.x でフォームの入力内容をバリデーションしています。
翻訳内容は YAML で保存しているため下記のようにして読み込んでいます。

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'locale' => "ja"
));
$app['translator'] = $app->extend('translator', function($translator, $app) {
    $translator->addLoader('yaml', new Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader());

    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__ . '/../resources/lang/ja.yml', "ja", 'validators');

    return $translator;
});
```

チェック箇所

```
$inputs = [
    "name" => $request->get("name")
];

$constraint = new Assert\Collection([
    'name' => new Assert\NotBlank()
]);

$errors = $app['validator']->validate($inputs, $constraint);
foreach($errors as $error){
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
```

ja.yml ファイルに

```
This value should not be blank.: 値が空です。
```

と書くことで getMessage() の結果を日本語化するところまで出来ましたが、例えば名前欄が空の場合「名前が空です。」といった表現をしたいと思っています。
Laravel のときは「:attribute の値 ”:value” は正しくありません」のような書き方をすることが出来ましたが、Silex ではどのようにするのが一般的なのでしょうか？

$error->getPropertyPath() を $app['translator']->trans() で翻訳して「:attribute」等のプレースホルダーをstr_replace() で置き換えれば一応の形にはなりそうですが正しい方法ではないように思えます。

いい方法がありましたらよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

フィールド（プロパティ）ごとにエラーメッセージを設定したい場合は、下記のように制約のコンストラクタに渡すオプション配列で独自のエラーメッセージを指定できます。

```
$constraint = new Assert\Collection([
    'name' => new Assert\NotBlank(['message' => '名前が空です']),
]);
```

独自のエラーメッセージの中でユーザーによる入力値を使いたい場合は `{{ value }}` というプレースホルダで参照できます。

```
$constraint = new Assert\Collection([
    'age' => new Assert\Range(['min' => 18, 'message' => '18歳未満は利用できません（{{ value }}歳と入力されています）']),
]);
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。値に関しては教えていただいた {{ value }} を用いるとして name に関しては yml ファイルで一括管理ではなく各コントローラーごとにそれぞれ書いていく形でしょうか。その場合 en, ja などのロケールの切り替えは利用できずに日本語のみと言うかたちになりますか？